# How to avoid doing checkpoint during savepoint

Tags: apache-flink

I got a question about manually taking savepoint.

I take a savepoint while my flink application is running. During the savepoint is being taken,the application continues to run and one or many new checkpoints will be created. And new data will be sinked to the outside storage.

When I stop the application and restart the application from the savepoint, the source is replayed from the position saved in the save point,which is too old.

So, there will duplicate data be written to the outside storage which breaks the end-to-end exactly once garantee.

I would ask how to avoid this situation, and the state is the latest state saved in the savepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink is capable of restoring jobs from checkpoints specifically if you are concerned of issues similar to this one (i.e. checkpoints are continuing and would be *more current* than your savepoints). You can do this if you are taking advantage of [externalized checkpointing](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/state/checkpoints//#resuming-from-a-retained-checkpoint):

```kotlin
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment().apply {            
    enableCheckpointing(checkpointingInterval)
    checkpointConfig.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(
      CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION)
    )
}
```

Which would be restored similar to what you would do with a savepoint:

```
bin/flink run -s :checkpointMetaDataPath [:runArgs]
```

This would ensure that you are restoring from your latest checkpoint while your savepoints would function as backups for the job that you could restore from.